# Where are the non-english characters on a Dvorak keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, dvorak, dead-keys

I recently decided to switch to the Dvorak keyboard layout, however I can't find an easy way to type non-english characters like `á`, `é` etc.

In fact, I had to switch back to QWERTY to type these in this question.

Is there a way to use dead keys for Dvorak with Windows 7? Or is there any other (better?) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any stock Windows Dvorak keymaps designed in this way, but you should be able to edit the stock one with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) to add them.

Comment: @Tiddo - Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

[Steven Ehrbar](http://personal.jargon-file.org/) maintains a collection of [alternate keyboards for Microsoft Windows](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/).  In the "General Purpose US Layouts" section you will find two Dvorak International layouts, one with raw dead keys and one where they're activated with AltGr+key combinations.  According to Ehrbar, the layouts work with Microsoft Windows XP and 2000, but perhaps they will work with later versions of Microsoft Windows as well, since they appear to be created with the Keyboard Layout Creator which Shinrai mentioned.

Another solution (depending on your situation) might be to use a different operating system.  All popular distributions of GNU/Linux come with International Dvorak layouts, some of which are even tailored to specific languages.